# Users and distribution groups not showing in GAL

Tags: exchange-2016, microsoft

I'm having issues with the GAL in Exchange 2016.
I have multiple companies running on 1 Exchange server which all have their own GAL, ABP etc..
I create them with Exchange management shell using these commands:

```
New-GlobalAddressList -Name "EXAMPLE-GAL"
New-AddressList -Name "EXAMPLE-AL" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -or (RecipientType -eq "MailUniversalDistributionGroup") -or (RecipientType -eq "DynamicDistributionGroup"))}
New-AddressList -Name EXAMPLE-Rooms -RecipientFilter {(Alias -ne $null) -and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox') -or (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'SyncedConferenceRoomMailbox')}
New-OfflineAddressBook -Name "EXAMPLE-OAB" -AddressLists "EXAMPLE-GAL"
New-AddressBookPolicy -Name "EXAMPLE-ABP" -AddressLists "\EXAMPLE-AL" -OfflineAddressBook "\EXAMPLE-OAB" -GlobalAddressList "\EXAMPLE-GAL" -RoomList "\EXAMPLE-Rooms"

Update-GlobalAddressList -Identity "EXAMPLE-GAL"
Update-AddressList -Identity "EXAMPLE-AL"
Update-AddressList -Identity "EXAMPLE-Rooms"
```

With Adsiedit.msc I have changed the following:

> Browse to Configuration–> CN=Microsoft Exchange –> CN=ORG –>
>   CN=Address Lists Container –> All Global Address List –> Right click
>   EXAMPLE-GAL and go to Properties. Look for the Attribute name
>   MsExchSearchBase and add the OU in the following format
>   OU=Example,OU=COMP,DC=company,DC=com

I have done the same with:

```
Configuration–> CN=Microsoft Exchange –> CN=ORG –> CN=Address Lists Container –> All Address Lists

EXAMPLE-AL and
EXAMPLE-Rooms
```

The users and distribution groups created in the OU `OU=Example,OU=COMP,DC=company,DC=com` all show fine in the `EXAMPLE-AL`, but none of them are showing in the `EXAMPLE-GAL` (I have checked the live `GAL` and they're also not showing there).

Am I missing out something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating the GAL, AL etc based on CustomAttribute instead of based on OU.

```
New-GlobalAddressList -Name "EXAMPLE-GAL" -RecipientFilter {(CustomAttribute1 -eq "EXAMPLE")}
New-AddressList -Name "EXAMPLE-AL" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -or (RecipientType -eq "MailUniversalDistributionGroup") -or (RecipientType -eq "DynamicDistributionGroup")) -and (CustomAttribute1 -eq "EXAMPLE")}
New-AddressList -Name EXAMPLE-Rooms -RecipientFilter {(Alias -ne $null) -and (CustomAttribute1 -eq "EXAMPLE")-and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox') -or (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'SyncedConferenceRoomMailbox')}
New-OfflineAddressBook -Name "EXAMPLE-OAB" -AddressLists "EXAMPLE-GAL"
New-AddressBookPolicy -Name "EXAMPLE-ABP" -AddressLists "\EXAMPLE-AL" -OfflineAddressBook "\EXAMPLE-OAB" -GlobalAddressList "\EXAMPLE-GAL" -RoomList "\EXAMPLE-Rooms"


Update-GlobalAddressList -Identity "EXAMPLE-GAL"
Update-AddressList -Identity "EXAMPLE-AL"
Update-AddressList -Identity "EXAMPLE-Rooms"
```

After adding a distribution group via Exchange ECP go to AD and open the properties for the created distribution group, go to attribute editor and set EXAMPLE for extensionAttribute1.

It is now showing in the company GAL and not showing in other companies GAL.
Keep in mind that if you use Outlook in cache mode, it can take a while (up to 24 hours) to show in the GAL.